# Add a search filter on RecyclerView with Cards?

Tags: android, filter, searchview, android-recyclerview

I found solutions for filters on `ListView` and `SearchView` on `RecyclerView` separately, but I wish to combine them. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Yes it is possible Your `RecyclerView.Adapter` can implement `Filterable`. After that you have to override `Filter getFilter()` method.

You have to define your own filter as is shown in the code below:

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new YourFilterClass();
}
```

**YourFilterClass**

```
class YourFilterClass extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            //Here you have to implement filtering way
            final FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            //logic to filtering
            results.values = ...
            results.count = ...
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            // here you can use result - (f.e. set in in adapter list)
        }
}
```

## Example

```
public class UserListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserListAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private final List<User> userList;

    private final List<User> filteredUserList;

    private UserFilter userFilter;

    public UserListAdapter(Context context) {
        this.userList =new ArrayList<>();
        this.filteredUserList = new ArrayList<>();
    }


    ///... other methods

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
       if(userFilter == null)
             userFilter = new UserFilter(this, userList);
        return userFilter;
    }

    private static class UserFilter extends Filter {

        private final UserListAdapter adapter;

        private final List<User> originalList;

        private final List<User> filteredList;

        private UserFilter(UserListAdapter adapter, List<User> originalList) {
            super();
            this.adapter = adapter;
            this.originalList = new LinkedList<>(originalList);
            this.filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            filteredList.clear();
            final FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (constraint.length() == 0) {
                filteredList.addAll(originalList);
            } else {
                final String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                for (final User user : originalList) {
                    if (user.getName().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filteredList.add(user);
                    }
                }
            }
            results.values = filteredList;
            results.count = filteredList.size();
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            adapter.filteredUserList.clear();
            adapter.filteredUserList.addAll((ArrayList<User>) results.values);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

After that in the place when you want to filtering call:

```
userListAdapter.getFilter().filter(text)
```

Comment: RecyclerView doesn't support filtering out-of-the-box, imho

Comment: @pskink As far I know no . Adapter from `RecyclerView` is a just `public static abstract class Adapter<VH extends ViewHolder> {` Maybe there is some mechanism but I don't know it. My solution works :)

Comment: who calls getFilter() then?  i don't see anything like that in RecyclerView code...

Comment: so your adapter doesn't need to implements Filterable, just use the custom Filter, thats it

Comment: you have to  implements Filterable because you need getFilter method.

Comment: Look on this line: `userListAdapter.getFilter().filter(text)` you call getFilter() on adapter

Comment: you can also use userListAdapter.getMyFancyFilter(), right?  so no Filterable is required

Comment: Yes that's right for this case :) but I you want use some mechanism which uses Filterable - you have to implement it. So better is use Filterable :)

Comment: Yeah it is helpful. But the implementation is getting dirty as I'm new to whole search and filter concept. Anyways I'll accept it. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I am glad that I could help you

Comment: no,  Filterable was needed by AbsListView for it to test if the Adapter support filtering,  it was done by testing "instanceof Filterable", your adapter support filtering so Filterable is not needed,  you dont need to test if it is an instance of Filterable

Comment: Good to know :) But in my project I used Filterable for my custom mechanism, I can create my own interface but Filterable was enough for me :)

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak I've implemented the whole search logic now how do I get the search bar, with SearchView? Or is it different in case of filter?

Comment: search.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String filterString) {
                yourAdapter.getFilter().filter(filterString);
                return  true;
            }
        });

Comment: It's a nice example but to be able to handle realtime on character change search you need to maintain the original list because for now it does keep only a filtered list

Comment: Works great. Thank you!

Comment: Works great too. Thank you!

Comment: You could simplify your code a bit if your user UserFilter class wasnt static

Comment: Please add this ans with ...... if (user.getName()..toLowerCase().trim().contains(filterPattern)) ...... so it wih match your search otherwise there will be not match  with contains

Answer (score 3):

**Here is complete sample code**

**Model Class**

```
public class Skills {

    int id;
    String skill;
    boolean isSelected;

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSkill() {
        return skill;
    }

    public void setSkill(String skill) {
        this.skill = skill;
    }
}
```

**Adapter Class**

```
private static final String TAG = SkillAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    protected List<Skills> mOriginalData = new ArrayList<>();
    protected List<Skills> mResultData = new ArrayList<>();

    protected Activity mActivity;
    OnRecyclerViewClick onRecyclerViewClick;
    private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();

    public SkillAdapter(Activity activity, OnRecyclerViewClick onRecyclerViewClick) {
        mActivity = activity;
        this.onRecyclerViewClick = onRecyclerViewClick;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_skill,
                parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final Skills data = mResultData.get(position);
        try {
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) holder;

            if (data != null) {
                viewHolder.checkSkill.setText(data.getSkill());
                viewHolder.checkSkill.setChecked(data.isSelected());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mResultData.size();
    }

    public void addItem(Skills exam) {
        mOriginalData.add(exam);
        mResultData.add(exam);
        int index = mOriginalData.indexOf(exam);
        notifyItemInserted(index);
    }

    public void removeItem(int index) {
        mOriginalData.remove(index);
        notifyItemRemoved(index);
    }

    public void removeItem(Skills exam) {
        int index = mOriginalData.indexOf(exam);
        mOriginalData.remove(exam);
        notifyItemRemoved(index);
    }

    public Filter getFilter() {
        return mFilter;
    }


    public Skills getItem(int index) {
        return mOriginalData.get(index);
    }

    public void replaceItem(int index, Skills audioMeta) {
        mOriginalData.set(index, audioMeta);
        notifyItemChanged(index);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CheckBox checkSkill;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            checkSkill = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.chkSkill);
            checkSkill.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onRecyclerViewClick.onItemClick(v, getLayoutPosition());
                }
            });
        }
    }


    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            int count = mOriginalData.size();

            final ArrayList<Skills> tempFilterList = new ArrayList<Skills>(count);

            String filterableString;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                filterableString = mOriginalData.get(i).getSkill();
                if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                    tempFilterList.add(mOriginalData.get(i));
                }
            }

            results.values = tempFilterList;
            results.count = tempFilterList.size();

            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            mResultData.clear();
            mResultData = (ArrayList<Skills>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

**In Activity Use**

```
    mAdapter = new SkillAdapter(SkillsActivity.this, SkillsActivity.this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

**Then Filter**

```
editSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            mAdapter.getFilter().filter(editSearch.getText().toString());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, your code is working, but how to load all data by default?

Answer (score 2):

Inside `Fragment Class` declare that:

```
protected List<User> mDataset;
protected List<User> mDataOrigin;
```

then inside `onCreate` add same source destination to both dataSet ant dataOrigin

```
mDataset = getObjectsFromDB();
mDataOrigin = getObjectsFromDB();
```

Finally use the magic function:

```
private void filterRecyclerView(String charText){
    charText = charText.toLowerCase();
    clearDataSet();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        mDataset.addAll(mDataOrigin);
    } else {
        for (User user : mDataOrigin) {
            if (user.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charText)) {
                mDataset.add(user);
            }
        }
    }
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Notice `User` is the list content you can replace with your Object have fun :)

Comment: future readers make sure you don't forget `mDataset = getObjectsFromDB();
mDataOrigin = getObjectsFromDB();` to set from the source itself or clone the mDataset, as i spent some hours looking into the issue by assigning `mDataOrigin = mDataset`, P.S. `mDataOrigin = mDataset.clone()` worked fine for me if you don't wanna hit db/func call