# How to implement a SearchView in Android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have created a `SearchActivity` based on a `RecyclerView` that should search through an `ArrayList<>` that I have declared in my `MainActivity`

```
public class SearchActivity extends ListActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        //DA IMPLEMENTARE: chiama accordo activity
        // do not care about this method, I'll implement it later
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            doSearch(query);
        }
    }

    private void doSearch(String queryStr) {
        // I think I should implement an adapter here
    }

}
```

I think I should implement something in the `doSearch()` method, but I do not know how to do it. I'd really appreciate if you could help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a Filter and implement Filterable on your RecyclerView Adapter. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29792187/add-a-search-filter-on-recyclerview-with-cards) out. or check this [tutorials](https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-adding-search-functionality-to-recyclerview/) if you dont want to use Filter method

Comment: thank you for your answer! should I create a new class called SearchFilter and then implement it in the `doSearch()` method?

Comment: No, use `onQueryTextChange` in your `doSearch ` method.  check the implementation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398247/how-to-filter-a-recyclerview-with-a-searchview/30429439#30429439

Comment: Heres a Video tutorial for better understanding of this concept https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XtEtsMoOLog

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out

Comment: how do I use this [tutorial](https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-adding-search-functionality-to-recyclerview/) if I have a separate search activity and I still want to search my main activity list?

Comment: Pass your arraylist from the mainactivity to the searchactivity with `Intent`, then provide the arraylist obtained from the mainactivity to the recyclerview in your search activity, and implement filterable on your recyclerview of searchactivity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116313/discussion-between-daniele-and-siddhesh-dighe).