# Return the arraylist to original list

Tags: java, android

## [On Hold] - Log.d reveals the private members of the adapter class changes everytime the filtering function is used. Even if the original data is kept while the filtered data is binded.

Note : [11.01.2017] Source code of RestInfoAdapter.java has since changed and updated (Refer to item number 2 below)

I have been trying to get my searchview to get back to the original list by keeping a backup/copy of the original input list. However it is not working at all. This problem of mine includes working with RecyclerView and ArrayList of a custom class.

`rInf_LIST` is an ArrayList of a custom class called `RestInfo` which stores the required information to have the app be useful
How I've been trying > 1 original arraylist, the ones the get binded to the UI elements. 1 copy of the original arraylist and 1 empty arraylist to store the filtered result. Once done, the arraylist that interacts with UI will have its value changed to the filtered list. If the search query is empty then, it should return the original list, which is where I'm failing
1. `VacancyList.java`

where the `searchView` resides (within `onCreate()`)

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vacancy_list);

    srchVw = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);
    srchVw.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
        {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
        {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }
    });

    /*miscellaneous codes*/

    rInf_LIST = new ArrayList<>();
    new NetworkTask(this, "listfirstTime").execute();

    //Setup Recycler View with the appropriate adapter and layout.
    recyclVw = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    adapter = new RestInfoAdapter(this, rInf_LIST);
    GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(this, 1);

    recyclVw.setLayoutManager(glm);
    recyclVw.setAdapter(adapter);

    refresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.refresh);
    refresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh()
        {
            new Handler().post(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    new NetworkTask(VacancyList.this, "list").execute();
                    Toast.makeText(VacancyList.this, "Refreshed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    refresh.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

2. `RestInfoAdapter.java` the adapter class so that RestInfo can be presented in a cardview (multiple therefore, recyclerview)

   ```
   public class RestInfoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RestInfoAdapter.RestInfo_ViewHolder> implements Filterable
   {
   public Filter filter;

   private Context context;
   private ArrayList<RestInfo> rInf_LIST;
   private ArrayList<RestInfo> filteredList;
   //Java Array starts at 0
   int selectedItemID = -1;

   public Context getContext()
   {return context;}

   public RestInfoAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<RestInfo> rInf)
   {
       this.context = mContext;
       rInf_LIST = rInf;
       filteredList = rInf;
       filter = new rInf_LIST_Filter();
   }

   @Override
   public RestInfo_ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
   {
       View itemVw = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);
       return new RestInfo_ViewHolder(itemVw);
   }

   //Binds 1 RestInfo to the UI elements
   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(final RestInfo_ViewHolder holder, int position)
   {
       RestInfo rInf = filteredList.get(position);
       holder.rName.setText(rInf.getRestName());
       holder.rLot.setText(rInf.getRestLot());
       holder.rVacancy_PROGBAR.setProgress(rInf.getResVacant());
       holder.progBarVal.setText(Integer.toString(rInf.getResVacant()/10));
   }

   @Override
   public int getItemCount()
   {
       return rInf_LIST.size();
   }

   @Override
   public Filter getFilter()
   {
       return filter;
   }

   private class rInf_LIST_Filter extends Filter
   {
       @Override
       protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence)
       {
           FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
           ArrayList<RestInfo> temp = new ArrayList<>();

           if(charSequence.length() == 0)
               temp.addAll(rInf_LIST);
           else
           {
               String filtrate = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

               for(int count = 0; count < rInf_LIST.size(); count++)
               {
                   if(rInf_LIST.get(count).getRestName().toLowerCase().contains(filtrate))
                       temp.add(rInf_LIST.get(count));
               }
           }

           results.values = temp;
           results.count = temp.size();

           return results;
       }

       @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
       @Override
       protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults)
       {
           Log.d("charSequence : ", Integer.toString(charSequence.length()));
           if(true)
           {
               filteredList.clear();
               filteredList.addAll((ArrayList<RestInfo>) filterResults.values);
               notifyDataSetChanged();
           }
       }
   }

   public class RestInfo_ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
   {
       public TextView rName, rLot, progBarVal;
       public ProgressBar rVacancy_PROGBAR;

       public RestInfo_ViewHolder(final View itemView)
       {
           super(itemView);

           rName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtVw_RestName);
           rLot = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtVw_RestLot);
           progBarVal = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.progBarTextValue);

           rVacancy_PROGBAR = (ProgressBar)itemView.findViewById(R.id.progBar);

           itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
           {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {
                   selectedItemID = getAdapterPosition();
                   Intent intent = new Intent(context, RestaurantInfo.class);

                   intent.putExtra("selected_Rest", filteredList.get(selectedItemID));
                   context.startActivity(intent);
               }
           });
       }
   }
   ```

   }
3. Data structure of `RestInfo` and the related method to get restName.

   ```
   //Displayed in CardView (and RestaurantInfo)
   //protected ImageView imgVw;
   protected String restName;
   protected String restLot;
   protected String restLoc;
   protected int restVacant;

   //Displayed in RestaurantInfo
   protected String restType;
   protected String restNo;
   protected String restEmail;

   //Displayed for Admin
   protected String restOwn;
   protected int restID;

   //Status
   private boolean objIS_EMPTY = true;

   public String getRestName(){
       return restName;
   }
   ```

## Edit 1

Logcat using Log.D
This is done in `publishResults` method. The purpose of this logging is to check if the lists are empty.

[PRE] tags are before `if(filterResults.count > 0)`. 

[POST] tags are after the `if(filterResults.count > 0) //evaluates false` and the `clear()` as well as `addAll()` methods

> 01-09 14:33:06.357 23159-23159/fyp.inrestaurant D/[PRE] filterResults: 0
>
> 01-09 14:33:06.357 23159-23159/fyp.inrestaurant D/[PRE] rInf_LIST: 5
>
> 01-09 14:33:06.357 23159-23159/fyp.inrestaurant D/[PRE] rInf_LIST_cpy: 5
>
> 01-09 14:33:06.367 23159-23159/fyp.inrestaurant D/[POST] filterResults: 0
>
> 01-09 14:33:06.367 23159-23159/fyp.inrestaurant D/[POST] rInf_LIST: 0
>
> 01-09 14:33:06.367 23159-23159/fyp.inrestaurant D/[POST] rInf_LIST_cpy: 0

## Edit 2

This is for when the conditional in Edit 1 is true

> 01-09 14:39:31.027 23159-23159/fyp.inrestaurant D/[PRE] filterResults: 3
>
> 01-09 14:39:31.027 23159-23159/fyp.inrestaurant D/[PRE] rInf_LIST: 5
>
> 01-09 14:39:31.027 23159-23159/fyp.inrestaurant D/[PRE] rInf_LIST_cpy: 5
>
> 01-09 14:39:31.027 23159-23159/fyp.inrestaurant D/[POST] filterResults: 3
>
> 01-09 14:39:31.027 23159-23159/fyp.inrestaurant D/[POST] rInf_LIST: 3
>
> 01-09 14:39:31.027 23159-23159/fyp.inrestaurant D/[POST] rInf_LIST_cpy: 3

## Edit 3

Added the updated code for logging `publishResults`

```
protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults)
    {
        Log.d("[PRE] filterResults", Integer.toString(filterResults.count)+"\n");
        Log.d("[PRE] rInf_LIST", Integer.toString(rInf_LIST.size())+"\n");
        Log.d("[PRE] rInf_LIST_cpy", Integer.toString(rInf_LIST_cpy.size())+"\n");
        if(filterResults.count > 0)
        {
            rInf_LIST.clear();
            rInf_LIST.addAll((ArrayList<RestInfo>) filterResults.values);
            Log.d("[POST] filterResults", Integer.toString(filterResults.count)+"\n");
            Log.d("[POST] rInf_LIST", Integer.toString(rInf_LIST.size())+"\n");
            Log.d("[POST] rInf_LIST_cpy", Integer.toString(rInf_LIST_cpy.size())+"\n");
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else
        {
            rInf_LIST.clear();
            rInf_LIST.addAll(rInf_LIST_cpy);
            Log.d("[POST] filterResults", Integer.toString(filterResults.count)+"\n");
            Log.d("[POST] rInf_LIST", Integer.toString(rInf_LIST.size())+"\n");
            Log.d("[POST] rInf_LIST_cpy", Integer.toString(rInf_LIST_cpy.size())+"\n");
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

## Edit 4

Added a new code suggestion

```
public RestInfoAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<RestInfo> rInf)
{
    this.context = mContext;
    rInf_LIST = rInf;
    rInf_LIST_cpy = new ArrayList<>(rInf);
    filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    filter = new rInf_LIST_Filter();
}
```

Logs does not show improvement (this is for false)

> 01-09 14:51:26.687 8198-8198/fyp.inrestaurant D/[PRE] filterResults: 0
>
> 01-09 14:51:26.687 8198-8198/fyp.inrestaurant D/[PRE] rInf_LIST: 5
>
> 01-09 14:51:26.687 8198-8198/fyp.inrestaurant D/[PRE] rInf_LIST_cpy: 0
>
> 01-09 14:51:26.687 8198-8198/fyp.inrestaurant D/[POST] filterResults: 0
>
> 01-09 14:51:26.687 8198-8198/fyp.inrestaurant D/[POST] rInf_LIST: 0
>
> 01-09 14:51:26.687 8198-8198/fyp.inrestaurant D/[POST] rInf_LIST_cpy: 0

When the conditional is supposed to be true. (5 of the data set has 3 that contains the character s)

> 01-09 14:53:01.427 8198-8198/fyp.inrestaurant D/[PRE] filterResults: 0
>
> 01-09 14:53:01.427 8198-8198/fyp.inrestaurant D/[PRE] rInf_LIST: 0
>
> 01-09 14:53:01.427 8198-8198/fyp.inrestaurant D/[PRE] rInf_LIST_cpy: 0
>
> 01-09 14:53:01.427 8198-8198/fyp.inrestaurant D/[POST] filterResults: 0
>
> 01-09 14:53:01.427 8198-8198/fyp.inrestaurant D/[POST] rInf_LIST: 0
>
> 01-09 14:53:01.427 8198-8198/fyp.inrestaurant D/[POST] rInf_LIST_cpy: 0

## Edit 5

Since there are questions on where rInf_List gets it's value, here are the codes of `onPostExecute()` and the related methods.

P/S @beeb, I've made a mistake, the method is not in onpostexecute instead, in the processfinish as NetworkTask is another class of it's own (since there are more than one activities needing to do NetworkTask, I made one class to reduce the code base)

tl:dr; version  of the code : processFinish sets the output to JSON Array. This array will then have it's members assigned to temp (RestInfo type) via a custom conversion method JSONArray_RestInf(). This temp variable will be added to the global variable rInf_List via RestInfo_ArrLst() method. Should there be a new item added, it will call notifyItemAdded(int position). If the previous item were the same, but additional data was given then notifyItemChanged will be called on the corresponding position.

```
@Override
public void processFinish(String output)
{
    boolean firstTime = Boolean.parseBoolean(output.substring(0, output.indexOf('e') + 1));
    output = output.substring(output.indexOf('e') + 1);

    if (!output.isEmpty())
    {
        try
        {
            jsArr = new JSONArray(output);

            for (int ctr = 0; ctr < jsArr.length(); ctr++)
            {
                RestInfo temp = JSONArray_RestInf(ctr);
                RestInfo_ArrLst(temp, firstTime);
            }
            Log.w("Size...", Integer.toString(rInf_LIST.size()));
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(VacancyList.this, "Failed to retrieve list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

//Converts the JSONArray to RestInfo
private RestInfo JSONArray_RestInf(final int index)
{
    RestInfo tempInf;

    try
    {
        ArrayList<String> tempArrLst = new ArrayList<>();

        //Converts JSONArray to ArrayList of strings
        for (String ctr : ELEMENTS)
        {
            tempArrLst.add(jsArr.getJSONObject(index).get(ctr).toString());
        }

        tempInf = new RestInfo(Integer.parseInt(tempArrLst.get(0)), tempArrLst.get(1), tempArrLst.get(2), tempArrLst.get(3), tempArrLst.get(4), Integer.parseInt(tempArrLst.get(5)), tempArrLst.get(6), tempArrLst.get(7), tempArrLst.get(8));

        return tempInf;
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return new RestInfo(0, "", "", "", "", 0, "", "", "");
    }
}

//Adds the temporary restaurant info to the array.
private void RestInfo_ArrLst(RestInfo tempInf, boolean firstT)
{
    if (!tempInf.getEMPTY_Status())
    {
        if (firstT)
        {
            rInf_LIST.add(tempInf);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else
        {
            boolean hasSameField;
            ArrayList<Boolean> hasChanged = new ArrayList<>(), isSimilar = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<Integer> changedPos = new ArrayList<>();

            //Loop to check for duplicates
            for (int ctr = 0; ctr < rInf_LIST.size(); ctr++)
            {
                hasSameField = (tempInf.checkFields(rInf_LIST.get(ctr)));
                if (tempInf.getRestID() == rInf_LIST.get(ctr).getRestID() && !hasSameField)
                {
                    rInf_LIST.set(ctr, tempInf);
                    changedPos.add(ctr);
                    hasChanged.add(true);
                }
                else if (tempInf.getRestID() == rInf_LIST.get(ctr).getRestID() && hasSameField)
                {
                    isSimilar.add(true);
                }
            }

            for(int ctr = 0; ctr < hasChanged.size(); ctr++)
            {
                if (!hasChanged.get(ctr)&& !isSimilar.get(ctr))
                {
                    rInf_LIST.add(tempInf);
                    adapter.notifyItemInserted(adapter.getItemCount() - 1);
                }
                else if (hasChanged.get(ctr))
                {
                    adapter.notifyItemChanged(changedPos.get(ctr));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem:

```
public RestInfoAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<RestInfo> rInf)
{
    this.context = mContext;
    rInf_LIST = rInf;
    rInf_LIST_cpy = new ArrayList<>(rInf);  // Create a new object. You don't want to use the same reference. :)
    filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    filter = new rInf_LIST_Filter();
}
```

Comment: I was about to make a question on how is it different. But you edited, still it isn't working at all. I think the new code is making a new arraylist that contains the arraylist that I wanted to work with (2 levels of arraylist instead of 1).

Comment: The `rInf_LIST_cpy` list creates a new copy of all objects. So when you perform `rInf_LIST.clear()` the  `rInf_LIST_cpy` should stay intact. Can you debug the `publishResults` method and see what's the size of all the lists?

Comment: If you mean logging them, I've added a new edit on the post. Something seems wrong.

Comment: I saw your logs. The problem should be solved by the code I have given you. Can you please recheck it.

Comment: In you logs it shows this `01-09 14:51:26.687 8198-8198/fyp.inrestaurant D/[PRE] rInf_LIST_cpy: 0`. Why is the list size 0 in PRE?

Comment: Logcat right after your proposed code in the constructor 01-09 15:12:14.327 25113-25113/fyp.inrestaurant D/new ArrList<>(rInf): 0

Comment: Yes I know. It shouldn't. Are you adding data to `rInf_LIST` in your `NetworkTask` in the first run too?

Comment: Yes it is initialized that way. I'll try to get a pastebin before I run out of space to type. rInf_LIST is definitely initialized on the execute()

Comment: Then initialize your adapter and set it to the RecyclerView in your task.

Comment: B it is, but I will be changing up the code soon as I realized the whole source code is full of `notifyDataSetChanged()` which isn't recommended by the docs. Hope that might shed some light

Comment: It isn't recommended in the docs to use `notifyDataSetChanged()` as `RecyclerView.Adapter` has methods like `notifyItemChanged`. For your use case where you are filtering data and setting a whole new set of items, it is the only way. Secondly, if you initialize and set your adapter when you have got the data from the server, the code above will work smoothly.

Comment: @NickyHFE - Have you got any solution for this? I am also facing same issue. Could you please share the solution if found.

Answer (score 0):

where you are using this kind of code to create a new list :filteredList.add(rInf_LIST_cpy.get(count));

try to create a new object RestInfo and save the value to this object and then add to list

Comment: that part of the code is working. The part that isn't is when I make an empty query which is supposed to return the original list.

Answer (score 0):

**First** of all you're init your adapter with an empty list:

```
rInf_LIST = new ArrayList<>(); // you create an empty list
new NetworkTask(this, "listfirstTime").execute();

//Setup Recycler View with the appropriate adapter and layout.
recyclVw = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
adapter = new RestInfoAdapter(this, rInf_LIST); // at this point your list is already empty
```

We can't see where you add your items (i think it's in `onPostExecute()` in `NetworkTask` right?).

**Second:** You have to create a copy of the original list because you don't want to modify the original list on filtering: `rInf_LIST_cpy = new ArrayList<>(rInf);`

**Third:** In your filter you only need to do this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
  rInf_LIST.clear();
  rInf_LIST.addAll((ArrayList<RestInfo>) filterResults.values);
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Because you already added the right objects to the result in `performFiltering()`

For more info check the accepted answer of this link: [Add a search filter on RecyclerView with Cards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29792187/add-a-search-filter-on-recyclerview-with-cards)

Comment: the value is retrieved from server in network task. notifyItemAdd or DataSetChanged is called in onpostexeccute. I've tried your solution but it is not working