# Search filter on RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i'm trying to implement search filter into my RecyclerView, just as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29792187/add-a-search-filter-on-recyclerview-with-cards)

The main issue i'm facing right now is on setOnQueryTextListener, inside my activity: "cannot find symbol class OnQueryTextListenerAdapter". It may be something i do need to create, or maybe i'm not implementing something on my activity. It is just  MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity.

My onCreateMenuOptions on activity is:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListenerAdapter() { @Override public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String filterString) { adapter.getFilter().filter(filterString); return true; } });

return true;
```

}

my adapter looks like this:

```
public class AnimeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AnimeAdapter.AnimeViewHolder> implements INameableAdapter {
    private List<Anime> items;
    private List<Anime> filteredItems;
    private AnimeFilter animeFilter;
```

with this:

```
 public Filter getFilter() {
        if(animeFilter == null)
            animeFilter = new AnimeFilter(this, items);
        return animeFilter;
    }

    private static class AnimeFilter extends Filter {

        private final AnimeAdapter adapter;

        private final List<Anime> originalList;

        private final List<Anime> filteredList;

        private AnimeFilter(AnimeAdapter adapter, List<Anime> originalList) {
            super();
            this.adapter = adapter;
            this.originalList = new LinkedList<>(originalList);
            this.filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            filteredList.clear();
            final FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (constraint.length() == 0) {
                filteredList.addAll(originalList);
            } else {
                final String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                for (final Anime anime : originalList) {
                    if (anime.getTitle().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filteredList.add(anime);
                    }
                }
            }
            results.values = filteredList;
            results.count = filteredList.size();
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            adapter.filteredItems.clear();
            adapter.filteredItems.addAll((ArrayList<Anime>) results.values);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

What i'm forgetting here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `OnQueryTextListenerAdapter` into `OnQueryTextListener`

[SearhView.OnQueryTextListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener.html)

Comment: thanks! it do compiles and filter now, but it does not seems to be reflected on screen.