# RecyclerView search filter clears the initial list and not able to search again

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement search in the recyclerview using filter and searchbar, when I do the search for the first time, it is displaying the results correctly. But as soon as I clear the search bar, it clears the entire list. It is supposed to display the `intialList` which I added from the API call. I might be messing up with the copying of my initialList but I not able to figure out how to fix it.

**Adapter**

```
Public class AdapterSearchList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterSearchList.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {

private Context context;
private final List<ModelMake> initialList;
private List<ModelMake> filteredList;

public AdapterSearchList(Context context) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.initialList = new ArrayList<ModelMake>();
    this.filteredList = new ArrayList<ModelMake>();
}

public void updateModels(List<ModelMake> newModels) {
    initialList.clear();//EDIT
    filteredList.clear();//EDIT
    initialList.addAll(newModels);
    filteredList.addAll(newModels);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    final ModelMake dataAdapter = initialList.get(position);
    viewHolder.itemName.setText(dataAdapter.getmName());
    viewHolder.itemId.setText(dataAdapter.getmId());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return filteredList.size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            String charString = charSequence.toString();
            if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                filteredList = initialList;

            } else {
                List<ModelMake> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (ModelMake row : initialList) {
                    if (row.getmName().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())) {
                        filteredList.add(row);
                    }
                }
                AdapterSearchList.this.filteredList = filteredList;
            }

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = filteredList;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            filteredList = (ArrayList<ModelMake>) filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();//EDIT

        }
    };
}


class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView itemName;
    public TextView itemId;
    public ImageView itemImage;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);
        itemName=itemView.findViewById(R.id.make_name);
        itemId=itemView.findViewById(R.id.make_code);

    }
}
}
```

**Fragment**

```
public class DialogFragmentMake extends DialogFragment {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private AdapterSearchList recyclerViewAdapter;
private SearchView searchView;
List<ModelMake> newModels = new ArrayList<>();

//...

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_make, container, false);
    //...
    searchView=v.findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
    recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewMake);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerViewAdapter = new AdapterSearchList(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
    GET_MAKE_WEB_CALL();
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //...
}


public void GET_MAKE_PARSE(JSONArray array) {

    //List<EventsDataModel> newModels = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        ModelMake GetSearchModel = new ModelMake();
        Log.i("SUCCESS", "Make web call success");
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);

            GetSearchModel.setmId(json.getString("VEHICLEMAKEID"));//
            GetSearchModel.setmName(json.getString("VEHICLEMAKENAME"));//
            newModels.add(GetSearchModel);

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (array.length() != 0) {
        String strArrayLen = String.valueOf(array.length());
        recyclerViewAdapter.updateModels(newModels);
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Your problem is both list holding same reference . This question has been answered several times here .  Don't do `this.filteredList = initialList;` . keep them separate

Comment: @ADM could you please explain it in the code, I tried several answers but not able to adapt it into my code.

Comment: just replace `this.filteredList = initialList;` with `this.filteredList = new ArrayList<ModelMake>()` . and inside `updateModels` you need call `addAll()` and `clear()` on both lists . Try this lets see if it works or not .

Comment: @ADM I did make the changes you suggested, But by calling `updateModels()` with the above mentioned changes in `publishResults()` its not showing the search result nor the initial list after searching. But by just adding `notifyDataSetChanged()` `publishResults()` gives the initialList back, but not the correct search result.

Comment: fix your filter logic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40754174/android-implementing-search-filter-to-a-recyclerview or https://stackoverflow.com/a/29792313/4168607